# debug centos7 kernel crash

Tags: kernel, crash

```
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: Modules linked in: iptable_raw xt_nat xt_mark xfrm6_mode_tunnel xfrm4_mode_tunnel veth esp4 ansi_cprng ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter xt_conntrack nf_nat tcp_diag inet_diag overlay binfmt_misc x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate mei_me lpc_ich intel_rapl_perf pcspkr joydev input_leds sg shpchp mei ioatdma mfd_core i2c_i801 wmi ipmi_si ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler acpi_power_meter acpi_pad ip_tables xfs sd_mod ast drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ttm ahci libahci drm ixgbe libata igb mdio ptp pps_core
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: i2c_algo_bit dca nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_conntrack libcrc32c crc32c_intel
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 22436 Comm: kworker/1:2 Not tainted 4.12.4-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: Hardware name: Supermicro X10DRi/X10DRi, BIOS 1.1 04/14/2015
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: Workqueue: xfs-buf/sda2 xfs_buf_ioend_work [xfs]
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: task: ffff88033c92c440 task.stack: ffffc90047178000
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: RIP: 0010:xfs_iflush_done+0x37/0x1f0 [xfs]
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffc9004717bd98 EFLAGS: 00010206
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: RAX: 6a5a2e42a4c9e303 RBX: ffff881014440000 RCX: 6a5a2e42a4c9e303
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000006 RDI: ffff880fedbedf80
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: RBP: ffffc9004717bdc0 R08: ffff881014440140 R09: 6613d90be9ba3a4a
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000018 R12: ffff880fedbedf80
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: R13: 989b74a08fa177ef R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff880fedbee020
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88103fa40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: CR2: 000000009956bb7c CR3: 0000000001c09000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: Call Trace:
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: xfs_buf_do_callbacks+0x35/0x50 [xfs]
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: xfs_buf_iodone_callbacks+0xb7/0x2a0 [xfs]
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: xfs_buf_ioend+0x9d/0x1e0 [xfs]
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: xfs_buf_ioend_work+0x15/0x20 [xfs]
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: process_one_work+0x149/0x360
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: worker_thread+0x4d/0x3c0
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: kthread+0x109/0x140
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: ? rescuer_thread+0x380/0x380
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: ? kthread_park+0x60/0x60
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x150
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: ret_from_fork+0x25/0x30
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: Code: 56 41 55 41 54 53 48 8b 87 e8 00 00 00 48 89 f3 4c 8b 6e 28 31 f6 48 85 c0 74 5a 31 d2 eb 0c 48 89 c2 48 8b 40 38 48 85 c0 74 4a <48> 81 78 40 c0 ac 3a a0 75 ea 48 85 d2 48 8b 48 38 0f 84 49 01 
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: RIP: xfs_iflush_done+0x37/0x1f0 [xfs] RSP: ffffc9004717bd98
2019-04-12T09:56:06+08:00 web10 kernel: ---[ end trace e6ea97e7e52e9395 ]---
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: Do the obvious stuff first: Run xfs_repair. Update the system.

Comment: `4.12.4-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64`  do you get this crash with the first party kernels from CentOS updates?

Comment: Do you have backtrace of crash? Hope this is not related to hardware issue.

Comment: we replace the original system disk (sandisk) to the intel dc s3510, and everything is fine now